# Choosing the right column based on a vector of column names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I'm trying to pull values from columns based on the values in a vector. I'm not sure I have the right words to describe the problem, but the code should help.

This feels related to `coalesce` maybe not?

```
library(tidyverse)
# Starting table

dat <- 
tibble(
  A = 1:10,
  B = 31:40,
  C = 101:110,
  value = c("A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A", "A")
)
```

I want:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(
    output = c(1, 102, 33, 4, 35, 106, 107, 38, 9, 10)
  )
```

I could do

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(
    output = 
      case_when(value == "A" ~ A,
                value == "B" ~ B,
                value == "C" ~ C)
  )
```

but my real application has many values and I want to take advantage of value having the matching info

Is there a function that does:

```
dat %>%
mutate(output = grab_the_right_column(value))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rowwise` approach would be less efficient, but it is compact within the tidyverse approaches to `get` the column value based on the column name for each row.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(output = get(value)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#       A     B     C value output
#   <int> <int> <int> <chr>  <int>
# 1     1    31   101 A          1
# 2     2    32   102 C        102
# 3     3    33   103 B         33
# 4     4    34   104 A          4
# 5     5    35   105 B         35
# 6     6    36   106 C        106
# 7     7    37   107 C        107
# 8     8    38   108 B         38
# 9     9    39   109 A          9
#10    10    40   110 A         10
```

---

These type of issues are more efficient with a row/column indexing approach from `base R`.  Create a `matrix` of row sequence and the `match`ing index of columns with the 'value' column and the column names to extract the element

```
dat$output <- as.data.frame(dat)[,1:3][cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)), match(dat$value, names(dat)[1:3]))]
```

Comment: This get() approach is awesome! I sometimes forget since get is called within the function call, you can use it to 'get' any object in the function (besides the global environment) environment, by name.

Answer (score 1):

**You can also use purrr and pmap()**:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat%>%mutate(output=
        pmap(., ~{
                v1<-c(...)
                v1[names(v1)==v1[['value']]]
                }
             )%>%
        as.numeric()%>%
        unlist)

# A tibble: 10 x 5
       A     B     C value output
   <int> <int> <int> <chr>  <dbl>
 1     1    31   101 A          1
 2     2    32   102 C        102
 3     3    33   103 B         33
 4     4    34   104 A          4
 5     5    35   105 B         35
 6     6    36   106 C        106
 7     7    37   107 C        107
 8     8    38   108 B         38
 9     9    39   109 A          9
10    10    40   110 A         10
```