# How to match values based on column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I  would like to identify the length of measurement was taken during a specific day based on `id` and `id1`. The measurement length is recorded in the `d1...d5` variables and `d_day` defines the length of the measurement I am looking for. For example in the first case, I am after `d3` measurement length that equals `30`. I tried the `which` functions but sure there are faster solutions.

Desired output

[image]

Data structure:

[image]

```
Sample data:

structure(list(id = c(101, 101), id_1 = c(1, 2), d1 = c(15, 0
), d2 = c(30, 15), d3 = c(25, 30), d4 = c(15, 30), d5 = c(15, 
60), d_day = c("d3", "d1")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), id_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), d1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), d2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), d3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), d4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), d5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), d_day = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing the right column based on a vector of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575405/choosing-the-right-column-based-on-a-vector-of-column-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(-c(id, id_1, d_day)) %>% filter(d_day == name) %>% 
     select(id, id_1, 'd_day_h' = value)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id  id_1 d_day_h
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1   101     1      25
2   101     2       0
```

Answer (score 1):

As your `d_day` contains already the column number it could directly used for subsetting which should be faster than using `match`.

```
cbind(x[1:2], d_day_h = x[3:7][cbind(seq_len(nrow(x)),
  as.numeric(substring(x$d_day, 2)))])
#   id id_1 d_day_h
#1 101    1      25
#2 101    2       0
```

Benchmark:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bench::mark(
   Gki = {cbind(x[1:2], d_day_h = as.data.frame(x[3:7])[cbind(seq_len(nrow(x)), as.numeric(substring(x$d_day, 2)))])}
 , KarthikS = {as.data.frame(x %>% pivot_longer(-c(id, id_1, d_day)) %>% filter(d_day == name) %>% 
                                     select(id, id_1, 'd_day_h' = value))}
 , GuedesBF = {as.data.frame(x %>% 
        rowwise %>%
        mutate(d_day_h = get(d_day)) %>%
        select(-c(d1:d_day))%>%
        ungroup)}
       )
#  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 Gki        288.74µs 306.78µs     3198.        0B     12.5  1538     6
#2 KarthikS     9.19ms   9.57ms      101.    25.1KB     11.2    45     5
#3 GuedesBF        6ms   6.52ms      151.    13.5KB     10.9    69     5
```

Currently method of GKi is about 20 times faster and uses less memory than the method form GuedesBF and about 30 times faster than the method from KarthikS.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach with `get()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
        rowwise %>%
        mutate(d_day_h = get(d_day)) %>%
        select(-c(d1:d_day))%>%
        ungroup

# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id  id_1 d_day_h
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1   101     1      25
2   101     2       0
```